# Dimension of largest submatrix with nonzero determinant equals rank

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $A \in M_{n\times n}(F)$ be nonzero. For any $m$, ($1 \leq m \leq n$), an $m \times m$ submatrix is obtained by deleting any $n-m$ rows and any $n-m$ columns of $A$. If $k$, ($1\leq k\leq n$) is the largest integer such that some $k\times k$ submatrix has nonzero determinant. Prove that rank$(A)=k$. (From Friedberg, Insel, Spence 4.3.23)

What I am having difficult with is if we consider the largest $k\times k$ submatrix with nonzero determinant, this means this submatrix is invertible and thus all $k$ columns are linearly independent. However,  this does not mean that those columns of $A$ are linearly independent since these column vectors of the submatrix are "chopped off" since the submatrix is of dimension $k \leq n$. So it doesn't follow that $A$ has $k$ linearly independent columns and we cannot conclude anything about its rank.

Answer (score 3):

You're wrong. Let $B$ be the $n\times k$ matrix consisting of those columns, and let $B'$ be the $k\times k$ submatrix of $B$ with nonzero determinant.

Consider the equation $Bx=0$ for $x\in\Bbb R^k$. Then note that $B'x=0$ holds (just consider the appropriate $k$ components or rows of the original equation). Since $B'$ is nonsingular, the only solution is $x=0$, and so the only solution of $Bx=0$ is likewise the trivial solution; this says that the columns of $B$ are, indeed, linearly independent.

Comment: Hello Sir, I do not understand "...the only solution is $x=0$, and so the only solution of $Bx=0$ is likewise the trivial solution". How can we conclude the last claim?

Comment: Read the proof. Starting with $Bx=0$ we deduced $x=0$. This means there is no nontrivial solution..

Comment: I do not see why because the only solution to $B'x=0$ is $x=0$ implies that the same must hold for $B$ since $Bx=0$ for $x$ possibly not equal $0$.

Comment: You do not understand the basic logic here. Do you not understand that whenever $Bx=0$, it follows that $B'x=0$? Write out matrix multiplication and look at it. Remember that you get $B'$ by crossing out rows of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Use that rank = row rank = column rank. Let $r$ be the rank of the original matrix $A.$ Form $B,$ by choosing $r$ linearly independent columns of $A.$ Form $C$ by choosing $r$ linearly independent rows of $B.$ Since the $r\times r$ matrix $C$ has rank $r,$ it has a nonzero determinant. (Observe that a submatrix cannot have larger rank than the original matrix.)